# Где Firefox хранит настройки о масштабе страницы?

Tags: html, sql, linux, firefox

Где Firefox хранит настройки о масштабе страницы?

Например, сейчас для данного сайта у меня выставлен масштаб в 110% и всякий раз, когда я открываю этот сайт, страница отображается в масштабе 110%. Где хранятся эти данные?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sqlite3 /home/vasya/.mozilla/firefox/asdfasdf.default/content-prefs.sqlite
```

Сам SQL запрос на выборку значения масштаба для данного сайта:

```
select p.value
from prefs p
join groups g 
  on p.groupID = g.id and g.name="ru.stackoverflow.com"
join settings s
  on s.name="browser.content.full-zoom" and s.id = p.settingID;
```

Answer (score 0):

я как то давно ковырялся, глянь тут --

C:\Users\пользователь\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\yfzogc03.dev-edition-default\prefd.js